# Removing a SKNode content and recreating it cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

'Cause of the difficulties I found combining `UITableView` and `SpriteKit Framework` I decided to develop a custom `SKTableView` (provided with full scrolling system). Everything works really fine but I have serious problem understanding an error I get during the update process.

My `SKTableView` shows the user a list of items in alphabetical order. Due to the tricky algorithm I should have create in order to update this list (*add a cell in a defined position, refresh the headers and scroll down all of the items*), I decided to simply update the database and reload the list (by removing existing content and recreate it) while showing asynchrony a notification to the user.

What is happen is the application to success reload the list once, once again, then after some random updates ... here comes the chaos

**Issues**

- The application crashes giving me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` during the `removeAllChildren` methods.
- The application crashes with the same error during a `for` statement (???) or during other statements
- The application crashes giving me `jet_context::set_fragment_texture...` error.

**Debug**:

- The console window doesn't show any kind of information.
- I can't monitoring the application using 'Allocation' or 'Zombies' instruments because it critically slow down the application. It takes more than 2 minutes to even load the SKTableView during the `init` method.

**Code**

*Interface*

```
/** Container for all the table items. */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SKNode *nodeContainer;
```

*Initialization*

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ...
        Create the style of the SKNode
        ...

        // Container initialization
        _nodeContainer              = [[SKNode alloc] init];
        _nodeContainer.position     = CGPointZero;
        _nodeContainer.zPosition    = 0;

        [self addChild:_nodeContainer];

        // Generate the content
        [self generateContent];
    }
    return self;
}
```

*Populate the table*

```
- (void)generateContent
{
    // Checks if the node exists, if it does, remove all of its children
    // Note: used for the recreation of the list
    if (_nodeContainer != nil)
        [_nodeContainer removeAllChildren];

    ...
    Initializes several SKSpriteNode and SKLabelNode
    ...

    [_nodeContainer addChild:imgItem];
    [_nodeContainer addChild:labelItem];
}
```

*Reload the content*

```
...
Update the database
...

[self showProgressNotification];

// Reload the content showing a notification
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Reload the content
    [self generateContent];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideProgressNotification];
    });
});
```

I really cannot figure it out what's happening. The code crashes overtime in a different line without a logic. I mean, is this the right way to remove and recreate items? Any advise?

Comment: looks like you have something hitting a null address,  did you stop all timers and actions prior to removal?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Looking around in this website I found something interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243514/adding-removing-and-caching-sknodes. It looks like with the 2 option is working fine

Comment: well then you are generating it in the wrong place if your answer is to remove parent from main thread

Comment: @Knight0fDragon What a stupid, I forgot to add the code about the async call. I have updated the question under *Reload the content*.